# Ability to disable ssms logging and changing data

Tags: sql-server, security

I wonder if there is a way to grant permission to an SQL server user to restore the database but not write data into the tables via ssms.
In fact, I don't want a user to go to the ssms and change data unless the user is "sa".
Is there a chance to perform it?

Answer (score 0):

If a Login is restoring an existing database, that database will contain any **user** permissions it previously had; if those users can/do map to **logins** on that server, then those Logins will map to those users and thus retain those permissions. You can't, for example, stop a user with the `db_datawriter` database role performing an `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, etc, on an object in the database, unless they also explicitly have a `DENY`. If, therefore, the Login is not an `sa` but can restore the database, and that `Login` maps to a user with "write" privileges, then they can write to the restored db. You **can't** stop that.

If you want to control who can write to a restored database, then the database administrator(s) should be the only Login's that can restore databases, then, have scripts set up that change the permissions on the newly restored database, which removes any user permissions to "write" to the database, and also removes any user's from the `db_owner` role.

Comment: tnx for your attention. Is there a way to encode database for ssms logins?

Comment: SSMS logins? SSMS doesn't have logins. When you use SSMS you provide the Login details for a SQL Server Instance. Much like when you connect to SO via your web browser (let's say FireFox); it's not a Firefox login, it's a Stack Overflow login, and you're connecting to Stack Overflow via Firefox.